# Divide polyline in equal parts

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line

I have shapefile with roads in one file. I want to divide this layer for example after 1000 meters. But there is problem, it is not polyline from one start point to end point. Do you know how this can be resolved?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your polyline is constructed (this will be messy if the line overlaps itself), you can create a point every 1000m and then split the line with the points.

- Create a new point feature class or shapefile
- start editing the new feature class
- select your polyline
- in the editor dropdown, select 'construct points'
- [image: List item]
- Select 'by distance' and input '1000' for the distance.  Make sure your map is set to meters for the units.
- [image: List item]
- Run tool 'Split line at point' - line input is your polyline, point input is the feature class you just created.

Comment: thanks, it is ok fro simple line but  there my line overlaps itself,

Comment: If the line overlaps itself, run 'Feature vertices to points', then 'Split line at points' using the points you just created.  Then use 'Unsplit Line' to merge the lines into one, non-overlapping line before running the process above.